# postgresql: вернуть и отсортировать часть json

Tags: json, postgresql

Если такой запрос

```
SELECT res FROM main WHERE id = 3;
```

возвращает данные (res - текстовое поле) в виде такой структуры json, например,

```
 {
 "abc": {
        "a": {
             "x": {"p": "val"},
             "y": {"p": "msg", "b": 33, "ms": 0},
             "z": {"p": "msg ", "b": 12, "ms": 0}
        },
        "b": ["x", "y", "z"], 
        "c": [
             [69, "text_05", "m n o"],
             [4, " text_02", "def"],
             [1, "text_01", "abc "],
             [48, " text_04 ", "jkl"],
             [5, " text_03 ", " ghi"],
             [82, "text_06  ", " pq r "]
             ]
 }
 }
```

то каким запросом можно получить и отсортировать только такое:

```
        [1, "text_01", "abc "],
        [4, " text_02", "def"],
        [5, " text_03 ", " ghi"],
        [48, " text_04 ", "jkl"],
        [69, "text_05", "m n o"],
        [82, "text_06  ", " pq r "]
```

Пробую через: from json_to_recordset .. as x(int,text,text), или: SELECT res::json->'abc'->'c' FROM main WHERE id = 3 ORDER BY .. ; - не получается.

upd1: Могу так, но без сортировки:

```
SELECT res::json->'abc'->'c' FROM main WHERE id = 3;
получаю:
             [
             [69, "text_05", "m n o"],
             [4, " text_02", "def"],
             [1, "text_01", "abc "],
             [48, " text_04 ", "jkl"],
             [5, " text_03 ", " ghi"],
             [82, "text_06  ", " pq r "]
             ]
```

Comment: Если такие запросы часты и в поле всегда json, то лучше колонку сделать не текстовую, а jsonb. Что бы не напрягать postgres парсингом текста каждый раз

Comment: понял, так и сделаю, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select json_agg(rec order by (rec->>0)::int)
  from (
    select json_array_elements(res::json->'abc'->'c') rec
      from main WHERE id = 3
  ) x
```

Это если на выходе хотите так же json. А если отдельными записями, то проще, json_agg не нужен, достаточно к обычной выборке добавить order by `(res::json->'abc'->'c'->>0)::int` ну и развернуть по столбцам по необходимости.